# Laravel Eloquent | Scope Functions

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Having a really hard time with a problem:

I have this scope function (which may not even be the right way to do this):

```
    public function scopeNonDepletedBottles(Builder $query, string $column, string $condition): Builder
    {
        $count = $this->bottles()->where('is_depleted', false)->count();

        return $query->where($column, $condition, $count);
    }
```

which is getting the count of a relationship with a certain criteria. Then it is comparing it to a column in the model.

This is the relationship:

```
    public function bottles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\InventoryItemBottle::class);
    }
```

I'm using it like so (see cases 3 and 4):

```
            ->when(isset($filters['filter_depleted']), function ($query) use ($filters) {
                switch ($filters['filter_depleted']) {
                    case 1: // Depleted. If item has bottles and if any are depleted or info->quantity is zero
                        $query->where(function ($q) {
                            $q->where(function ($q) {
                                $q->whereHas('bottles', function ($q) {
                                    $q->where('is_depleted', true);
                                });
                            })->orWhere(function ($q) {
                                $q->whereDoesntHave('bottles')->where('info->quantity', 0);
                            });
                        });
                        break;
                    case 2: // Not Depleted. If item has bottles that are not depleted or info->quantity is greater then zero
                        $query->where(function ($q) {
                            $q->where(function ($q) {
                                $q->whereHas('bottles', function ($q) {
                                    $q->where('is_depleted', false);
                                });
                            })->orWhere(function ($q) {
                                $q->whereDoesntHave('bottles')->where('info->quantity', '>', 0);
                            });
                        });
                        break;
                    case 3: // Below Threshold. Where count of NOT DEPLETED bottles or info->quantity is less than low_level_warning
                        $query->where(function ($q) {
                            $q->nonDepletedBottles('info->low_level_warning', '>')
                                ->orWhere(function ($q) {
                                    $q->whereColumn('info->quantity', '<', 'info->low_level_warning');
                                });
                        });
                        break;
                    case 4: // Above Threshold. Where count of NOT DEPLETED bottles or info->quantity is greater than high_level_warning
                        $query->where(function ($q) {
                            $q->where(function ($q) {
                                $q->nonDepletedBottles('info->high_level_warning', '<');
                            })->orWhere(function ($q) {
                                $q->whereColumn('info->quantity', '>', 'info->high_level_warning');
                            });
                        });
                        break;
                }
            })
```

However... it isn't working as expected. Where I expect to see results, I see non, and where I don't, I see a whole bunch.

Is the use of scopes even appropriate here?

Ultimately for cases 3 and 4, I'm looking to get `InventoryItem`'s that have bottles count of less then or greater then `info->low_level_warning` and `info->high_level_warning` respectively.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a scope function, **you could try** defining a method on the model itself that performs the same logic:

```
public function getNonDepletedBottleCount(): int
{
    return $this->bottles()->where('is_depleted', false)->count();
}
```

Then you can use this method in your query:

```
case 3: // Below Threshold. Where count of NOT DEPLETED bottles or info->quantity is less than low_level_warning
    $query->where(function ($q) {
        $q->where(function ($q) use ($low_level_warning) {
            $q->whereHas('bottles', function ($q) {
                $q->where('is_depleted', false);
            })->where(function ($q) use ($low_level_warning) {
                $q->where('info->quantity', '>', $low_level_warning)
                  ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($low_level_warning) {
                      $q->where('info->quantity', '=', 0)
                        ->where('info->low_level_warning', '>', 0);
                  });
            });
        })->orWhere(function ($q) use ($low_level_warning) {
            $q->whereDoesntHave('bottles')->where('info->quantity', '<', $low_level_warning);
        });
    });
    break;
```

And similarly for case 4.

Comment: The thing is the `$low_level_warning` is dynamic. So each model would have a different value (most likely).